# Get filename from CameraRoll.getPhotos() [React Native IOS]

Tags: react-native, filenames, camera-roll

How do I get the **filename** from `CameraRoll.getPhotos()` ?

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 1000000, assetType: "All", groupTypes: "All" })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

I can get the **file uri** and **file type** but not **filename** . I mean there is no filename been returned.

Here is the output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the expo-media-library
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/###

```
const getLocalUri = async () => {
let uri = "ph://ED7AC36B-A150-4C38-BB8C-B6D696F4F2ED/L0/001"
let myAssetId = uri.slice(5);
let returnedAssetInfo = await MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(myAssetId);
console.log(returnedAssetInfo.localUri); // you local uri link to get the file
}
```

Remember to install unimodules if not using Expo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unimodules

source: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll/issues/52#issuecomment-564641652

Answer (score -1):

You can get the file uri, file type and filename

```
res.node.image.filename
```